# How can I read an in-memory HDF byte array back into a pandas DataFrame without writing a file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf

I can convert a pandas dataframe to an HDF byte array like so:

```
        data = ...  # a pandas dataframe

        with pd.HDFStore(
                "in-memory-save-file",
                mode="w",
                driver="H5FD_CORE",
                driver_core_backing_store=0,
        ) as store:
            store.put("data", data, format="table")
            bytes_to_write = store._handle.get_file_image()
```

`bytes_to_write` now contains the DataFrame.

I need to convert this buffer back to a DataFrame.

The `pandas.read_hdf` method accepts a `pandas.HDFStore`, but this class seems like can only be constructed using a file path, not a buffer.

But how can I convert this byte array back to a DataFrame?

I'm on Python 3.9.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, this seems to be an unresolved request : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31902